IEntityModel vs IEntity in Typescript
I could see there are different conventions for declaring models or interfaces in TypeScript.
Which one is correct or recommanded as
export interface ISomeModel {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

export interface ISomeDto {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

export interface ISome {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

Any documentation references or examples or pros cons.
